# Can't extract geo keys

Tags: mongodb, geolocation, geojson, 2dsphere

I try create 2dsphere index in mongodb, but i get error

> "Can't extract geo keys: { _id: ObjectId('57963b5365ba4df2c13a4965'),
>   loc: { coordinates: [ -180.0, 65.33018130000001 ], type: \"Point\" } }
>   longitude/latitude is out of bounds, lng: -180 lat: 65.3302"

Why is it happening?